# Can a 'while loop' be used in actionscript to monitor an event dispatch?

Tags: actionscript

I am creating an action script library.I am calling some APIs which parses some xml and gets me the result. It dispatches an Event.COMPLETE when the parsing is done. I want to monitor whether this event is dispatched in some while loop like "while(eventnotdispatched)"
is it possible? I know the other way would be to addeventlistener. But please let me know if the other thing is possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: Davr is right, you would not be able to use the while loop like this. You would need a timer.

Yes, it is possible to poll for it. BUT you will still need to create an event listener. It will work something like this:

```
private var loadCompleted = false;
private var timer:Timer= new Timer(1);

private function onInitCompleted(event:Event):void
{

    timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, timerHandler);
    timer.start();
}

private function loadCompleteEventHandler(event:Event):void
{
    loadCompleted = true;
    ...
}

private function timerHandler()
{
    if(!loadCompleted)
    {
        ... // stop the timer or something.
        timer.stop();
    }
}
```

Please note, this is VERY BAD code. I would NEVER use it in production because Actionscript is a event driven language. There should be absolutely NO REASON for you to need to do this. Whatever you are trying to do could be accomplished using another method much simpler. Tell me what you are trying to accomplish with this and I will present a better solution.

Sorry for yelling, it's late and I am sleepy.

Comment: +1 for telling him it's a bad idea, -1 for thinking it might work. actionscript is single-threaded, your code would never work as you intend.

Comment: yes, you're right, it wouldn't, blame the lack of sleep. I made edits to use a timer.

Answer (score 3):

NO, it is not possible. Actionscript is single threaded. Thus while you are waiting in your while loop, that is the only thread running, and the process you are waiting for can never complete. This is why everything is done with events, so that's what you should use. If you need to update your display periodically while you are waiting for something to complete...again, use events. Create a Timer object which generates a TIMER event every so often, and use that to make your updates.

Answer (score 0):

Doing that means forcing a synchronous model of execution on the underlying asynchronous model (that works with callbacks).

What are you trying to achieve exactly, and why not use a callback?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the statements about it probably being a bad idea and a while loop will certainly not work this way in ActionScript. However, there may be legitimate reasons for doing what you are attempting to do. Only you can prevent bad code.  Instead of judging, I'll just get to an answer for your question.

First I'm going to make an assumption, that what you really want to do is monitor a property and for some reason the API for this object does not dispatch an event when this property changes. I'm making this assumption because if you have the event available, I assume you would just use the event.

So...    you have an object **weirdXmlObj** with a property **loaded** that defaults to **false** but goes to **true** when the XML is loaded.

In this case with slight modifications the code posted by CookieOfFortune would in fact work.  You wouldn't need the **loadCompleteEventHandler** function (which was never attached anyway) and in the timer handler you would simply check **if( weirdXmlObj.loaded )** and then branch however you wanted to.

Ah but there may be a simpler way, depending on what you are doing.
If you have a display object handy. (i.e. something that makes sense, not just some random object.)  You can attach your code to the stage's EnterFrame event instead of using a timer.

**myDisplayObject.stage.addEventListner(Event.ENTER_FRAME,frameEnterHandler);**

A couple of things to be aware of:

1. You don't really even need to go to the stage level, all display objects support the EnterFrame event, but it's a nice place to attach the event listener.
2. You really should keep whatever the function calls to a minimum.  In particular the actual **frameEnterHandler** function should do nothing more than do the **if( weirdXmlObj.loaded )** check.

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to circumvent event-driven programming, which is not a good idea. This is often the case when someone approaches from an older model and does not yet have a good frame of reference to appreciate the elegance of event-driven programming.

Events are your friends. They work very well. Your loadCompleteHandler is all that is required. Want to do something else in response? Add the call in that handler:

```
private function loadCompletedHandler(event:Event):void
{
    waitingObject.fileWasLoadedSoGoDoThatThing();
}
```

There is no need to make it any more complicated than that. No need for a semaphore or a loop to check the semaphore. Unnecessary environmental semaphores can break the encapsulation that could shield you from unwanted side effects.